# Как привести к дате строку /Date(-62135575200000)/?

Tags: javascript, json, дата

Получаю от сервера данные в таком виде `/Date(-62135575200000)/`, что это за формат времени? Как из него получить читаемую дату используя javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date

Comment: видел этот вопрос перед тем как создать свой, но, например, `var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));` отдает не корректную дату. А остальные решения которые нашел отдают `invalid date`.